# ZIO watch file system events

Tags: scala, nio, zio

help me how to organize a directory scan on ZIO. This is my version, but it doesn't track all file creation events (miss some events).

```
object Main extends App {

  val program = for {
    stream <- ZIO.succeed(waitEvents)
    _ <- stream.run(ZSink.foreach(k => putStrLn(k.map(e => (e.kind(), e.context())).mkString("\n"))))
  } yield ()

  val managedWatchService = ZManaged.make {
    for {
      watchService <- FileSystem.default.newWatchService
      path = Path("c:/temp")
      _ <- path.register(watchService,
        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE
      )
    } yield watchService
  }(_.close.orDie)

  val lookKey = ZManaged.make {
    managedWatchService.use(watchService => watchService.take)
  }(_.reset)

  val waitEvents = ZStream.fromEffect {
    lookKey.use(key => key.pollEvents)
  }.repeat(Schedule.forever)

  override def run(args: List[String]): ZIO[zio.ZEnv, Nothing, ExitCode] =
    program
      .provideLayer(Console.live ++ Blocking.live ++ Clock.live)
      .exitCode
  
}
```

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forcing your `WatchService` to shutdown and recreate every time you poll for events. Since that probably involves some system handles it is likely fairly slow so you would probably missing file events that occur in between. More likely you want to produce the `WatchService` once and then poll it repeatedly. I would suggest something like this instead:

```
object Main extends App {        
  val managedWatchService = ZManaged.make {
    for {
      watchService <- FileSystem.default.newWatchService
      path = Path("c:/temp")
      _ <- path.register(watchService,
        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE
      )
    } yield watchService
  }(_.close.orDie)
      
  // Convert ZManaged[R, E, ZStream[R, E, A]] into ZStream[R, E, A]
  val waitEvents = ZStream.unwrapManaged(
    managedWatchService.mapM(_.take).map { key =>
      // Use simple effect composition instead of a managed for readability.
      ZStream.repeatEffect(key.pollEvents <* key.reset)
       // Optional: Flatten the `List` of values that is returned
       .flattenIterables
    }
  )

  val program = waitEvents
    .map(e => (e.kind(), e.context()).toString)
    .foreach(putStrLn).unit

  override def run(args: List[String]): ZIO[zio.ZEnv, Nothing, ExitCode] =
    program
      .provideLayer(Console.live ++ Blocking.live ++ Clock.live)
      .exitCode
  
}
```

Also as a side note, when using `ZManaged`, you probably don't want to do

```
ZManaged.make(otherManaged.use(doSomething))(tearDown)
```

because you will cause the finalizers to execute out of order. `ZManaged` can already handle the ordering of teardown just through normal `flatMap` composition.

```
otherManaged.flatMap { other => ZManaged.make(doSomething(other))(tearDown) }
```